# How to send a query to Stimulsoft in C#?

Tags: c#, stimulsoft

I am learning to use stimulsoft.net in Visual Studio with C# and I work with FirebirdSql.

Instead of passing parameters, I would like to pass to the report the complete SQL query with the where clause as complex as it needs.

Can someone help me with the instruction to pass the query in C#?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

this is working in `Asp.Net Core 2.0` and need to install the package `Stimulsoft.Reports.Web.NetCore` version `2018.3.5`.

```
StiReport report = new StiReport();
report.Load(@"C:\report.mrt"); // laod report
((Stimulsoft.Report.Dictionary.StiSqlSource)report.Dictionary.DataSources.Items[0]).SqlCommand = "select * from People where ID > 10";
report.Render();
```